# SQL Server 2008 - How to Convert ntext to int list?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have column with the type `ntext`, and I would like to convert it into list of int. Column is called `ValidForCustomers` and contains Ids of customers comma separated.

I know I can cast it to `nvarchar(max)` but when I do it SQL throws error

> Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Part of the query

```
select Items from Split(c.ValidForCustomers, ',')
```

**This is query**

```
select top 100 
*,c.CouponCode, 
c.Description,
case when c.CouponType = 0 then 'Order - this coupon ONLY applies to the order subtotal'
else 'Product - this coupon ONLY applies to the specified product(s)' end as CouponType,
case when c.DiscountIncludesFreeShipping = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as FreeShiping,
case when c.ExpiresAfterOneUsageByEachCustomer = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as 'ExpiresAfterOneUsageByAnyCustomer',
case when c.ExpiresOnFirstUseByAnyCustomer = 0 then 'No' else 'Yes' end as 'ExpiresOnFirstUseByAnyCustomer',
c.ExpiresAfterNUses,
case when len(CAST(c.ValidForCustomers as nvarchar(max))) = 0 THEN 'No'
    ELSE cstms.CustomerNames END as 'ValidForCustomers',
CASE when LEN(CAST(c.ValidForProducts as nvarchar(max))) = 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'No' END as 'ValidForProducts',
CASE when LEN(CAST(c.ValidForCategories as nvarchar(max))) = 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END as 'ValidForCategories'
    from Coupon c with(nolock)        
    cross apply ( select CustomerNames = (SELECT SUBSTRING((SELECT ',' + cust.FirstName + ' ' + cust.LastName
                FROM Customer cust
                inner join (select IntegerFromList from dbo.fn_StringListToIntList(CAST(c.ValidFOrCustomers as nvarchar(max)), ',')) sp on (sp.IntegerFromList= cust.CustomerID)                
                ORDER BY cust.FirstName
                FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000))) as cstms
```

This is procedure for converting

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StringListToIntList]
(
  @IntegerList  NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @Delimiter    CHAR(1) = '|'
)
RETURNS @IntegersTable TABLE (IntegerFromList  INT)
AS
BEGIN
  IF (@IntegerList IS NULL) OR (LEN(@IntegerList) = 0) OR (@Delimiter IS NULL) RETURN

  DECLARE  @DelimPos INT
  SELECT  @DelimPos = PATINDEX('%' + @Delimiter + '%', @IntegerList)

  WHILE @DelimPos <> 0
  BEGIN
    --If nothing between delims, save as NULL
    IF LEN(SUBSTRING(@IntegerList, 1, @DelimPos - 1)) = 0
      INSERT INTO @IntegersTable(IntegerFromList)  VALUES(NULL)
    ELSE
      INSERT INTO @IntegersTable(IntegerFromList)
      VALUES(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(@IntegerList, 1, @DelimPos - 1)))

    SELECT @IntegerList  = SUBSTRING(@IntegerList, @DelimPos + 1, LEN(@IntegerList))
    SELECT @DelimPos  = PATINDEX('%' + @Delimiter + '%', @IntegerList)
  END --While...

  --If no additional chars after a final delim, treat as an additional NULL
  IF LEN(@IntegerList) = 0
    INSERT INTO @IntegersTable(IntegerFromList)  VALUES(NULL)
  ELSE
    INSERT INTO @IntegersTable(IntegerFromList)  VALUES(CONVERT(INT, @IntegerList))

  RETURN 

END --Function
```

and the error is

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near '('.
```

and everything is OK with syntax

Comment: You shouldn't be storing a list of integers in a single field - this is completely non-relational, even violating 1NF.

Comment: @Oded, whats to say the data isn't imported as such.

Comment: (1) The 'ntext' datatype is deprecated (2) A list of comma delimited numbers won't need Unicode (double the space requirement) (3) What Oded said.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko - Nothing. And you should still not store it that way...

Comment: Where are you getting that split function?  Is that function what you're looking for?  There is not a built-in Split function in SQL Server, but there are lots of examples of custom TDF out there which do that.

Comment: Ok to give you a clue, I work for the company which uses Out of the box solution for Shopping cart, and there is Coupon that is valid for bunch of customers, Customer Ids are recorded in field ntext and I can't do it differently, i would like if it was another table with the list of ids, but this is situation, I don't need help how to build database I have 47 databases and every of them have this, and I need to create report.

Comment: Omit parts of your query, and see if it starts working.  This should help narrow down the part of the query that is causing the problem.  For example, run `select Items from dbo.fn_StringListToIntList(CAST(c.ValidFOrCustomers as nvarchar(max)), ',')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created custom function for returning string of Customers,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetCustomersForCoupon](
    @CouponID int
)
returns nvarchar(MAX)
as
Begin
declare @Str nvarchar(max)
declare @IntTable table ( ID int)
declare @ValidForProducts nvarchar(2000)

select @ValidForProducts = ValidForCustomers from Coupon where CouponID=@CouponID
insert into @IntTable (ID) select * from dbo.fnStringListToIntList(@ValidForProducts, ',')
SELECT @Str = SUBSTRING((select ',' + Replace(p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName, '<Name>','') from @IntTable t
inner join Customer p on (p.CustomerID = t.ID)
FOR XML PATH('')),2,200000)

return @Str
end
```

now it works as a charm, but directly from query, as subquery it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good syntax for `cast`:

```
select  *
from    dbo.Split(cast(c.ValidForCustomers as nvarchar(max)), ',')
```

Does that give an error?

The schema `dbo` is not optional when you're calling a user-defined function.

Answer (score 0):

Since all numbers are ids of customers, what you can instead do is check each customer's id, to check if it's in the list.

```
SELECT Customer.Id
FROM MyTableWithTextField
INNER JOIN Customer
ON MyTableWithTextField.TextField LIKE CAST(Customer.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',%'
OR MyTableWithTextField.TextField LIKE '%,' + CAST(Customer.Id AS VARCHAR(10)) + ',%'
OR MyTableWithTextField.TextField LIKE '%,' + CAST(Customer.Id AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Yes, this is hideous and will probably perform badly, but that's unavoidable if you try to store a variable number of values in a single field. A much better idea would be to create a new table.

Comment: That is to many checks, I hav elike 100000 customers and 10000 coupons and each coupon have 10-20 customers